# I'm not sure what the issue is here with my solution to the coding problem Rotate the Array?

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, queue

```
class Solution
{
    //Function to rotate an array by d elements in counter-clockwise direction. 
    static void rotateArr(int arr[], int d, int n)
    {
       Queue<Integer> buffer = new PriorityQueue<Integer>();
       
       for(int j = 0; j < d; j++)
       {
         buffer.offer(arr[j]); //Where the excpetion occurs 
       }
       for(int i = 0 ; i < n;i++)
       {
        if(i<n-d){
            arr[i]=arr[i+d];
            
        }
        else{
            arr[i]=buffer.poll();
        }
       }
    }
}
```

```
The Exception shown. I'm not sure why index 47 is an issue considering the array is 
for input (77 int long array, rotate by 69, 77 random integers ...)

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 47 out of bounds for length 47
    at Solution.rotateArr(File.java:62) marked by comment in code
    at GFG.main(File.java:36)
```

I was expecting code to execute without error
Works fine with small input such as (5,2,(1,2,3,4,5))
Very strange, can't find any logical significance for the index 47 providing an exception since the array in 77 chars long

Answer (score 0):

> ...can't find any logical significance for the index 47 providing an exception since the array in 77 chars long

Note that code challenge sites will run your code with different inputs one after the other.

When you get an error saying *"java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 47 out of bounds for length 47"*, you can be absolutely sure that the array has a length of 47, not 77.

You may be confusing the value of `d` with the length of the array. `d` is the value to rotate the array by, and your code should deal well with cases where this `d` is **greater** than the last index of your array. In that case you'll run into this exception.

To avoid this error, first bring that value of `d` in range. It is clear that if you rotate the array by its length, you get the original array. So you can reduce `d` by that much until it is less than the size of the array. You can use the `%` operator for that. Put this at the start of your function:

```
d %= n;
```

Now you'll no longer get the exception.

### Another issue

After the above fix you'll still get wrong results. A priority queue is not what you need here, because its `poll` method will provide you with values in order of priority (i.e. in this case by their value). This is not what you want. You'll want the values to come out in first-in-first-out order. For that you can use a linked list. So change your buffer to this:

```
Queue<Integer> buffer = new LinkedList<Integer>();
```

With these two fixes your code should provide the correct results.

Finally, you may want to up the challenge a bit and try to solve this without O() auxiliary memory.

Answer (score -1):

This code may help you for rotate array in anti-clockwise using normal array without using Queue.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner Object = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter Array Length: ");
        int ArrayLength = Object.nextInt();

        int[] Array = new int[ArrayLength];
        /* Getting Inputs */
        for (int i = 0; i < ArrayLength; i++) {
            Array[i] = Object.nextInt();
        }

        /* rotating arrray */
        /* condition for j value limits number of times rotate */
        for (int j = 0; j < Array.length; j++) {
            int first = Array[0];

            for (int k = 0; k <Array.length-1 ; k++) {
                Array[k] = Array[k + 1];
            }
            Array[Array.length-1] = first;

            /* Print Array values */
            for (int i = 0; i < Array.length; i++) {
                System.out.print(Array[i] + "  , ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }

    }
}
```